# How to configure Message Driven Bean Application & Glassfish to consume messages from remote Message Broker?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, jms, messaging

I've created a simple MDB application and deployed it to Glassfish v 3.1 with embedded MQ broker. Destination Resource with name "jms/Queue" was created as well.
Please see part of the code below:

```
    @MessageDriven(
       mappedName = "jms/Queue",
       activationConfig = {
          @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        }
    )

    public class MessageBean implements MessageListener {

         public void onMessage(Message message) {
........
```

This works fine, but how to configure this application to work with remote MQ broker instance(located on another host)?

Comment: Please add more details. Do you have 2 GlassFish instances, one in ServerA, and one in ServerB, and you want that both instances use the MQ broker of ServerA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- [Use the REMOTE mode](http://www.packtpub.com/article/configuring-jms-resources-in-glassfish-1) when configuring your JNDI resources for `ConnectionFactory` and `Queue` entities so these entities are hosted by a remote OpenMQ.
- Configure a bridge to connect together two queues hosted in difference instances. Here is the [documentation reference](http://mq.java.net/4.4-content/jmsbridge-funcspec.html) about that feature.

Comment: Could you please tell how to configure connectionFactory and associate it with MBean?

Comment: MBean often refers to JMX entities... I guess you mean MessageBean. I cannot be more clear that the description and Glassfish admin console snapshot from the link about "REMOTE" mode. Please read it carefully. End of part 1 is about ConnectionFactory creation in JNDI.